# Embedding Pentaho 3.9.1 Reports in Jboss AS 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, module, pentaho

We have embedded Pentaho Reports 3.9.1 in Jboss 5.1 the code works fine. But when we have migrated to Jboss 7.1.1 it doesn't work.

During ClassingEngineBoot.getInstance().start() I get this output on my log.

```
20:20:00,822 INFO [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibBase 1.2.8.16112 started. 
20:20:00,828 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibSerializer 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,852 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibLoader 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,853 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibFormula 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,854 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibFonts 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,855 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibFormat 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,862 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibXML 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,863 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibRepository 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:00,863 INFO  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) LibDocBundle 1.2.8.16112 started.
20:20:01,070 WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/D:/seam2.3/work/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/pentaho/main/ehcache-core-2.0.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
20:20:01,084 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Failed to create data cache: javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory
20:20:01,086 WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/D:/seam2.3/work/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/pentaho/main/ehcache-core-2.0.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
20:20:01,097 WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/D:/seam2.3/work/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/pentaho/main/ehcache-core-2.0.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
20:20:01,113 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageState] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Unable to initialize the module core-module
20:20:01,113 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.common.GuiCommonModule not initializable.
20:20:01,114 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.configstore.base.ConfigStoreBaseModule not initializable.
20:20:01,114 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.csv.CSVModule not initializable.
20:20:01,115 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule not initializable.
20:20:01,115 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.base.TableBaseModule not initializable.
20:20:01,116 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.support.itext.BaseFontModule not initializable.
20:20:01,116 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.beanshell.BeanShellModule not initializable.
20:20:01,116 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.bsf.BSFModule not initializable.
20:20:01,117 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.tablemodel.TableModelModule not initializable.
20:20:01,117 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule not initializable.
20:20:01,118 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.survey.SurveyModule not initializable.
20:20:01,118 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.xml.XMLModule not initializable.
20:20:01,119 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.external.ExternalDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,119 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,119 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.reflection.ReflectionDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,120 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.table.TableDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,120 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.drilldown.DrillDownModule not initializable.
20:20:01,121 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.legacy.charts.LegacyChartElementModule not initializable.
20:20:01,121 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.plugin.jfreereport.reportcharts.LegacyChartModule not initializable. 
20:20:01,122 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.jfreereport.legacy.LegacyFunctionsModule not initializable.
20:20:01,122 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.modules.rhino.RhinoModule not initializable.
20:20:01,122 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.modules.sbarcodes.SimpleBarcodesModule not initializable.
20:20:01,123 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.modules.sparklines.SparklineModule not initializable.
20:20:01,123 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.toc.TocModule not initializable.
20:20:01,124 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.common.GuiCommonModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.commonswing.SwingCommonModule not initializable.
20:20:01,124 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.csv.CSVTableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,125 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.html.HtmlTableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,125 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.graphics.Graphics2DPageableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,126 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.plaintext.PlainTextPageableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,126 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.support.itext.BaseFontModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.rtf.RTFTableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,126 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.xls.ExcelTableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,127 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.configstore.filesystem.FileConfigStoreModule not initializable.
20:20:01,127 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.DataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,128 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.ext.ExtParserModule not initializable.
20:20:01,128 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.base.PageableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.xml.XmlPageableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,129 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.base.TableBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.table.xml.XmlTableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,129 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule not initializable.
20:20:01,130 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.data.compounddata.CompoundDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,130 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.data.external.ExternalDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,131 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.data.inlinedata.InlineDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,131 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.data.sql.SQLDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,132 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.data.staticdata.StaticDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,132 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.simple.SimpleParserModule not initializable.
20:20:01,133 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineCoreModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.modules.java14config.Java14ConfigModule not initializable.
20:20:01,133 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.commonswing.SwingCommonModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule not initializable.
20:20:01,134 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.graphics.Graphics2DPageableModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.pdf.PdfPageableModule not initializable.
20:20:01,135 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.ext.ExtParserModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.extwriter.ExtWriterModule not initializable.
20:20:01,135 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.wizard.WizardCoreModule not initializable.
20:20:01,135 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.csv.CSVExportGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,136 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.html.HtmlExportGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,136 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.pdf.PdfExportGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,137 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.plaintext.PlainTextExportGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,137 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.print.AWTPrintingGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,138 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.rtf.RTFExportGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,138 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.SwingPreviewModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.xls.ExcelExportGUIModule not initializable.
20:20:01,139 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.pdf.PdfPageableModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.referencedoc.ReferenceDocModule not initializable.
20:20:01,139 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.cda.CdaModule not initializable.
20:20:01,139 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.hibernate.HibernateDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,140 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.kettle.KettleDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,141 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.mondrian.MondrianDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,141 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.olap4j.Olap4JDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,142 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.PmdDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,142 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.scriptable.ScriptableDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,143 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.xpath.XPathDataFactoryModule not initializable.
20:20:01,143 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.bundle.BundleXmlModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.sampledata.SampleDataModule not initializable.
20:20:01,144 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.cda.CdaModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.cda.CdaDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,144 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.hibernate.HibernateDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.hibernate.HibernateDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,145 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.kettle.KettleDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.kettle.KettleDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,145 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.mondrian.MondrianDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.mondrian.MondrianDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,146 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.olap4j.Olap4JDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.olap4j.Olap4jDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,146 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.pmd.PmdDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.pmd.PmdDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,147 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.scriptable.ScriptableDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.scriptable.ScriptableDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,147 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.xpath.XPathDataFactoryModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.xpath.XPathDataSourceModule not initializable.
20:20:01,148 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.print.AWTPrintingGUIModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.modules.java14print.Java14PrintModule not initializable.
20:20:01,148 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Required dependency 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.parser.base.ParserBaseModule' for module 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.parsers.reportdesigner.ReportDesignerParserModule not initializable.
20:20:01,149 ERROR [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) class org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineBoot failed to boot: : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Booting the report-engine failed.
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineBoot.performBoot(ClassicEngineBoot.java:352) [pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core-3.9.1-GA.jar:3.9.1-GA.16112]
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.AbstractBoot.start(AbstractBoot.java:197) [libbase-1.2.8.jar:1.2.8.16112]
    at com.highwaycabs.chms.action.reports.pentaho.ReportServlet.init(ReportServlet.java:39) [chms2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Booting the report-engine failed.` is caused mainly due to incompatible jar files between the Pentaho and server. It seems that the upgraded version of JBoss 7.1 is having compatibility issues with the version of pentaho.

Check out [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?90154-Booting-the-SDK-engine-in-an-application-server) link.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Its not able to initialize the core module. Is it because of incompatible jars - Can you specify the incompatible jar list ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a dependency org.antlr to the pentaho module worked